# Single PID run two commands

Tags: python-3.x

When I check the process from the bash, it display:

```
In [42]: !ps
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
  417 ttys000    0:00.49 -bash
 7783 ttys000    0:06.50 /Users/me/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/me/anaconda3/bin/ipython
```

It seems that pid 7783 run two commands simultaneous,

Could please provide any hints help understand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is running only one command but with one argument:

```
/Users/me/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/me/anaconda3/bin/ipython
^ command                      ^ argument
```

Python scripts are not directly executable. An interpreter is required to actually run them. Similarly, in your case the command is the `python` *interpreter*, and the argument is the `ipython` *script*.

When you directly execute the script, the operating system peeks inside to see if it has a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). This is a line starting with `#!` (actually the byte sequence `0x2321`) followed by the path to the program meant to run the file. For example, on my system the `ipython` script points at the `python3.7` interpreter:

```
$ head -1 $(which ipython3)
#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7
```

Calling the script automatically expands to calling the shebang program with  the script. Thus, you never see the actual script being run by itself - only the interpreter running the script.

```
$ ipython3 -c '!ps' | grep ipython3
5764 ttys004    0:00.37 /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python /Users/miyagi/Library/Python/3.7/bin/ipython3 -c !ps
```